# For any user-given text file, the program will read, analyze, and write each word with the line numbers where the word is found in an output file

Tags: python, dictionary

For any user-given text file, the program will read, analyze, and write each word with the line numbers where the word is found in an output file. A word may appear in multiple lines. A word shows more than once at a line, the line number will be only recorded one time.
Ask a user to enter the name of a text file. Using try/except for invalid user input. Then the program reads the contents of the text file and create a dictionary in which the key-value pairs are described as follows:

- Key. The key are the individual words found in the file.
- Value. Each value is a list that contains the line numbers in the file where the word (the key) is found. Be aware that a list may have only one element.

Once the dictionary has been built, the program should create another text file, named “word_index.txt”. Next, write the contents of the dictionary to the file as an alphabetical listing of the words that are stored as keys in the dictionary (sorting the keys), along with the line numbers where the words appear in the original file.

*see my code below*

```
import string

fname = input('Enter a file name: ')

try:
    fhand = open(fname)
except:
    print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
    exit()

counts = dict()
L_N=0
for line in fhand:
    line= line.rstrip()
    line = line.translate(line.maketrans(' ', ' ',string.punctuation))
    line = line.lower()
    words = line.split()
    L_N+=1
    for word in words:
        if word not in counts:
            counts[word]= [L_N]
        else:
            if L_N not in counts[word]:
                counts[word].append(L_N) 
for h in range(len(counts)):
    print(counts)

out_file = open('word_index.txt', 'w')
out_file.write('Text file being analyzed is: '+str(fname)+ '\n\n')
out_file.close()
```

The outcome should print the results once but I am having an issue where it is printing multiple times at once.

Comment: You have a loop (`for h in range(len(counts))...`) that repeatedly prints the same dictionary.

Comment: That's because you're printing your dictionary n times where n is the dictionary length, you can loop through your dictionary using this syntax: `for key, value in counts.items():`

Comment: Where should i add for key?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're printing your dictionary in the for loop it will be printed n times - *n is the length of dictionary* -  so you need just to remove this loop:

```
for h in range(len(counts)):
    print(counts)
```

And add this instead:
here we just loop through dictionary to get every pairs

```
for key, value in counts.items():
    print('key: ', key, 'value: ', value)
```